# How to check whether our query is transformed or not in the Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle, sql-tuning

**How to check whether my query is transformed or not by the Query Transformer?**

I've searched on the Internet but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Query transformation is just a step in the optimization process, it would be unusual to care whether any transforms were done (particularly for things like converting modern SQL 92 joins to Oracle's old outer join syntax).  You can look at a query plan to see if a particular transform has been done (i.e. look to see if a particular predicate has been pushed into a view) but there isn't a "did the transformation step do anything" flag.

Comment: Check the [execution plan](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/EXPLAIN-PLAN.html#GUID-FD540872-4ED3-4936-96A2-362539931BA0)

Answer (score 0):

Justin Cave: *"it would be unusual to care whether any transforms were done"*

I disagree. There are excellent reasons for MTO or anyone else to want to know if query transformation has occurred. Here are four:

1. Learning. See in action specific characteristics that cause the optimizer to transform or to not transform a query.
2. Get an idea if a query that doesn't transform is missing a needed bitmap index.
3. Check the timing and resource usage of a transformed query Vs. the original.
4. Having that great quality we share as Oracle professionals: **curiosity**!

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33365764)